# Kernel Update past 5.0.0-25-generic breaks wifi on Dell Laptop

Tags: wireless, dell, adapter

I have linux kernel 5.0.0-25 installed with working wifi. Any attempt to update past this version results in no wifi adapter found. Is there a way to  back up the wifi adapter so I can reinstall it after a kernel update? Or is there an easier way. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

#### Edit 1:

```
$ dkms status

bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.0.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Is this the first kernel update you'll done? Did you have to install extra software to get this adapter working in the first place?

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `dkms status`.

Comment: 5.0.0-25 was the first update and it worked without any additional effort. Software updater offered 5.2.9 and 5.2.10 but when installed no wifi adapter was found.  Had to revert via grub to get it back. Then UKUU to clean up the grub.

Comment: question edited with dkms status results

Comment: It's most likely that the driver software doesn't support a kernel that new. You may want to check to see if there is updated software for your WiFi. Question: do you really need the 5.2.x series kernel?

Comment: Thanks, I will check for updated software but you are right, I don't really need to update the kernel. I am just a little curious though, if there isn't a way to update without loosing the wifi adapter should I get use to the idea that this is the only kernel this machine will have going forward? And should I be concerned?

Comment: @MinMinValenti - if everything else works with the new kernel, then just search for an update to the WiFi drivers. Any time you upgrade a kernel, there's a chance that some module is not going to build properly.

Comment: thanks  ajgringo619 using software update switched wifi adapter from the linux version and wifi still worked. then I updated the kernel again and this time it did not break the wifi.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to be patient for the developers to release driver updates for newer kernels. When 5.2 isn't supported the first step would be to try 5.1 kernels.

Comment: If you want to avoid such problems with the third-party drivers in the future, you could also just replace the WiFi/BT module in your laptop with an Intel or Atheros model which is supported with open source drivers in upstream kernel, instead.

Answer (score 0):

`dkms status` shows us:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.0.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
```

the bcmwl wi-fi module is only built for kernel 5.0.0-25.

Any manual or UKUU kernel update would require a manual `dkms add/build/install` to build it for the newer kernel.

re: "Software updater offered 5.2.9 and 5.2.10 but when installed no wifi adapter was found".

`Software Updater` would never offer these kernels, unless you've modified your repos, or unless you mean `UKUU`.